# "View Device Logs" option does not show all the logs in Xcode on one Mac

Tags: xcode, crash-log

I noticed when I develop apps using different Macs(i.e. office-Mac and home-Mac), every time I plug the iDevice(iPhone, iPod...) with Mac, click the `View Device Logs` button under `Window` -> `Devices and Simulators` option, there are some (crash)logs in one Mac and others in another Mac. Or sometimes

My question is:

1. why this is the case?
2. How can I view all the logs in one Mac?
3. Is there another way to view/analyze (crash) logs of iDevices correctly and conveniently without using Xcode?

Here is my environement:

- macOS: High Sierra(home-Mac), Sierra(office-Mac)
- Xcode: 9.2, 8.3.3
- iDevice: iPhone SE(iOS 10.3.3), iPod Touch 5th-Gen(iOS 8.2)

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Similar problem here, often the log for a recent crash just doesn't appear on the list.  Sometimes it shows up eventually.  I have done a lot of searching and haven't found any solution.